# How do we generate Precision Recall curves when we have two output neurons, each determining the probability of belonging to the same class?

Tags: roc, precision-recall, model-evaluation

For classification using neural networks, if we have only one output neuron, we can vary the threshold for class labeling and get a Precision Recall (PR) curve.
I am using cross entropy loss, after applying softmax on the output layer, where the output layer has 2 neurons. For labeling, I am using **argmax(y_1,y_2)**. How can I get a PR curve in this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just apply softmax on your last layer. The output of softmax is the probability of each class and sums up to 1. So argmax(y_1, y_2) means that you get softmax and apply a threshold of 0.5 for choosing y_1. This means if the probability of y_1 is more than 0.5 then you choose y_1. You can just apply softmax and then set another threshold for y_1. Hope this helps.